# RTCPeerConnection is not a constructor, in Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, safari, webrtc

I'm programming a very simple WebRTC application to stream real-time video from a RaspberryPi Zero camera. I'm using [Linux Project's UV4L driver](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/) to setup the server and JavaScript to connect and play the video stream. My JavaScript code is based on [UV4L's demo](https://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/custom-webapp-with-face-detection/), which essentially uses RTC web socket methods to perform negotiation.

Their code works beautifully in Chrome, but doesn't seem to work under Firefox or Safari.

```
RTCPeerConnection = window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription;
RTCIceCandidate = window.RTCIceCandidate;
var ws;

function signal(url, onStream, onError, onClose, onMessage) {    
    if("WebSocket" in window) {
        var pc;
        ws = new WebSocket(url);

        ws.onopen = function () {
            var config = {"iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]};
            pc = new RTCPeerConnection(config);     // <---- ERROR here.
            pc.onicecandidate = function (event) {
                // ... ICE negotiation.
            };

            if('ontrack' in pc) {
                pc.ontrack = function(event) {
                    // ... set stream object and play
                };
            } else {  // onaddstream() is deprecated
                pc.onaddstream = function (event) {
                    // ... set stream object and play
                };
            }
            // ... other event listeners.
            ws.send(...); // Signals the remote peer to initiate a call
        };
    }
}
```

In particular, I get an error When I try to connect, the following error is thrown in Firefox v60.0.1 (and a very similar in Safari):

> TypeError: RTCPeerConnection is not a constructor

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/RTCPeerConnection), Firefox has support for this constructor since v22. What could be the issue?

Comment: seems to be `RTCPeerConnection` is not constructable. did you try removing the `new`?

Comment: I've just tried, and both Chrome and Firefox complain. Error message says that `RTCPeerConnection` cannot be used as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error turned out to be a silly typo. The declaration of RTCPeerConnection at the beginning of the code, was wrong. It should be:

```
RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
```